# Darle estilo a un optgroup en navegador movil (CSS)

Tags: css

Tengo un select con optgroup que le cambio el color para destacar mas el titulo los options

```
optgroup[label] {
   color: grey;
   font-style: inherit;
   font-weight: 300;
   text-shadow: none
}
```

Pero en el navegador movil no me detecta este cambio, no me permite formatear, me muestra el select por defecto.

La pregunta es: existe codigo css o javascript para

Comment: Me temo que en mobile no es una opción, he buscado así por encima en google (con enlaces a stackoverflow) y parece ser que coge el estilo del sistema operativo. Los `selects` son los elementos que menos puedes modificar con CSS. La mejor opción, es crear uno propio con JS

Comment: tienes razon amigo, yo tambien me e revisado todo san google y nada, una consulta, tu que ya has estado en estos terrenos no podrias recomendarme algun script para reemplazar el select y solucionar este problema ?